# Debugging javascript previousSibling returns unexpected result, why?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm assuming what Chrome shows me when I 'Inspect Element' is the correct DOM.

I have javascript to get the previous sibling for a DIV tag, which should be another DIV tag, however it is returning '#text'

Here is my DOM as shown in chrome.  The highlighted element is the object I am calling getPreviousSibling on.

DOM 
[image: DOM]

**javascript**:

```
var sibling = selectedDiv.previousSibling;
```

Comment: Try `previousElementSibling` if the browsers you target support it. Chances are there is a text node (probably a newline) right before your `<div>` element.

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.